# Symfony 2 Redirecting localized page on Login Failure

Tags: symfony, redirect

Well, I'm using localisations and login form.

My login form URLs looks like:

```
mysite.com/en/login.html
mysite.com/ru/login.html
mysite.com/it/login.html
etc...
```

when login credentials is OK, it redirects user to corresponding localized homepage:

```
mysite.com/en
mysite.com/ru
mysite.com/it
```

But if credentials are bad it redirects me always to english page:

```
mysite.com/en/login.html
```

So user always seeing english localized errors, no matter which locale he used.
This situation is not surprising me because the route for login page has default _local value:

```
login:
    path: /{_locale}/login.html
    defaults: { _controller: MySitePortalBundle:Security:login, _locale: en }
    methods: [GET]        
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|it|en
```

BUT! How to learn my application to redirect erroneous users to correct _locale page?

p.s. I read this ["Redirecting on Login Failure"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-on-login-failure/), but this is not resolve my problem.

**UPD:**

security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                failure_path: login_failure
                check_path: login_check
```

routing.yml:

```
login_failure:
    path: /{_locale}/login.html 
    defaults:  { _controller: MySitePortalBundle:Security:login, _locale: en }    
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|it|en        

login_check:
    path: /login_check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application redirects to default locale because the login process goes throught login_check path. And if there a no {_locale} parameter in routing of this path it use default _locale of application.

Good configs are:

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                check_path: login_check
                failure_path: login_failure
```

**routing.yml:**

```
login_failure:
    path: /{_locale}/login.html 
    defaults:  { _controller: MySitePortalBundle:Security:login, _locale: en }    
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|it|en        

login_check:
    path: /{_locale}/login_check
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|it|en
```

After adding {_locale} parameter to login_check route it wont be lost inside login process.

Answer (score 2):

If you include your security.yml config and relevant routing configs, it would be easier to see what you are doing.  But I think you are missing something in your routing.yml along with your security.yml file.

From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-on-login-failure) that you mentioned, you need the following in security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                failure_path: login_failure
```

now in the routing.yml file you need something like this:

```
login_failure:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/homepage
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|it|en
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.  I think you were just missing the necessary route config.

When you specify the {_locale} in the route, symfony2 should store the locale in the session, so the application should be aware of where to redirect.  You can read more about this on the docs - [the locale and the url](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url)